# Cannot build .tex file on Texnic Center (The memory dump file could not be found)

Tags: bibtex, miktex, texniccenter

I am running `MikTex 2.9` on Windows 8 and i am trying to compile my first .tex file. I face the following error when i try to build latex->PS or latex->PDF.

```
latex> latex.exe: The memory dump file could not be found
latex> latex.exe: Data: latex.fmt
BibTex> I couldn't open file name 'prac.aux'
```

I have checked that the directories are correct and i have ghostscript viewer and adobe reader for PS and PDF formats respectively. I tried other solutions such as 'Run as administrator' and `initexmf --dump` but it didn't work. I also tried reinstalling MikTex 2.9 but to no avail.

I then tried to go to `Start => Programs => MiKTeX 2.9 => Maintenance => Settings` and `Update Formats` as suggested in some solutions but i faced the following error:

'The MikTex configuration utility failed. Do you want to see the transcript?'

If I click 'Yes', then a new windows appears with lot of text. I have pasted few top lines below. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
Creating the latex format file...
Running miktex-pdftex.exe...
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (INITEX)
entering extended mode
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\config\latex.ini"
(C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic
\config\pdftexconfig.tex
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\latex.ltx"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\texsys.cfg")
./texsys.aux found     

\@currdir set to: ./.

Assuming \openin and \input 

have the same search path.


Defining UNIX/DOS style filename parser.

catcodes, registers, compatibility for TeX 2,  parameters,

LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> patch level 2

hacks, control, par, spacing, files, font encodings, lengths,

====================================

Local config file fonttext.cfg used

====================================

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\fonttext.cfg"

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fonttext.ltx"

=== Don't modify this file, use a .cfg file instead ===

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\omlenc.def")

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def")

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ot1enc.def")

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\omsenc.def")

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1cmr.fd")

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ot1cmr.fd")

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ot1cmss.fd")

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ot1cmtt.fd")))

====================================

Local config file fontmath.cfg used

====================================

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\fontmath.cfg"

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontmath.ltx"

=== Don't modify this file, use a .cfg file instead ===

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\omlcmm.fd")    

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\omscmsy.fd")

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\omxcmex.fd")

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ucmr.fd")))

====================================

Local config file preload.cfg used

=====================================

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\preload.cfg"

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\preload.ltx")) page nos., x-ref,
environments, center, verbatim, math definitions, boxes, title, sectioning,

contents, floats, footnotes, index, bibliography, output,

===========================================

Local configuration file hyphen.cfg used

===========================================

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\cslatex\base\hyphen.cfg"

Loading english hyphenation patterns and exceptions

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\hyphen\hyphen.tex")

! LaTeX Error: Encoding scheme `IL2' unknown.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.

Type  H <return>  for immediate help.

 ...                                              



l.131 ...                        \@requesthyphens}

No pages of output.

Transcript written on latex.log.

miktex-makefmt: miktex-pdftex.exe failed on latex.ini.    
initexmf.EXE: The operation failed for some reason.
initexmf.EXE: Data: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-    makefmt.exe
```

Comment: You will have to show more lines. The error is somewhere below.

Comment: i added all the text in that transcript

Comment: Looks like you got the broken babel package - it was for a short time available and you seem to have install miktex just then. Run an update with the package manager (admin).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you mean to synchronize in package manager (admin)?

Comment: Sorry I meant the update manager (admin). But you can also use the package manager to deinstall and reinstall babel. Whatever gets rid of the faulty version is fine.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Update manager said that there are no updates currently available. And in package manager, I uninstalled 'babel' and 'babelbib' and reinstalled but still the error remains. Should I try to unistall MikTex 2.9 and redownload and install it altogether?

Comment: Try another repository. I got the new babel from ftp.fernuni-hagen.de. Also check with the admin and the user tools (I don't know how you did install babel and which version of the tools must update it.)

Comment: Same problem here with the latest MiKTeX and TeXStudio (Win7 64bit). pdflatex.exe does also not work in a command shell with the same error message: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
pdflatex.exe: The memory dump file could not be found.
pdflatex.exe: Data: pdflatex.fmt

Comment: There is an error in the placement of the babel hyphen.cfg. It got in tex/tex/generic instead of tex/generic. Either move it and update the fndb (with miktex settings (admin), or deinstall the cslatex package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer do you mean to move hyphen.cfg file from tex/tex/generic/babel to tex/generic/babel?

Comment: Yes. Why don't you simply try it?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried it first and updated formats but same error occured, so I was asking to confirm. But now, I realized you were saying to refresh fndb rather than update formats. I refreshed fndb after moving the files as you said and it worked. Omg, thanks a lot. I thought that I wont be able to use latex on windows. Thanks again mate. Now, post it as answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently a bug in the babel package from miktex. The files are in `tex/tex/generic/babel` instead of `tex/generic/babel`.

This is a problem if the cslatex package is installed as now its hyphen.cfg is found before the hyphen.cfg from babel.

Until the package is repaired you can do the following:

1. Move the hyphen.cfg from `tex/tex/generic/babel` to `tex/generic/babel`.
2. Refresh the FNDB in miktex settings (admin)
3. Update the formats.